# gunicorn access log format

Tags: python, json, gunicorn, fluentd

I'm planning to run flask through gunicorn at kubernetes. To get the logging right, I want to output all my logs in json.

Currently I'm testing with minikube and https://github.com/inovex/kubernetes-logging to have fluentd collecting the logs.

I managed to get the errorlogs (tracebacks) properly formated thanks to:
[JSON formatted logging with Flask and gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753214/json-formatted-logging-with-flask-and-gunicorn)

I'm still struggling with the access log format.
I specified the following gunicorn access log format:

```
access_log_format = '{"remote_ip":"%(h)s","request_id":"%({X-Request-Id}i)s","response_code":"%(s)s","request_method":"%(m)s","request_path":"%(U)s","request_querystring":"%(q)s","request_timetaken":"%(D)s","response_length":"%(B)s"}'
```

And the resulting log is json formated. But the message part (format based on access_log_format) now contains escaped double quotes, and will not be parsed by fluentd / ELK into it's individual fields

```
{"tags": [], "timestamp": "2017-12-07T11:50:20.362559Z", "level": "INFO", "host": "ubuntu", "path": "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/glogging.py", "message": "{\"remote_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"request_id\":\"-\",\"response_code\":\"200\",\"request_method\":\"GET\",\"request_path\":\"/v1/records\",\"request_querystring\":\"\",\"request_timetaken\":\"19040\",\"response_length\":\"20\"}", "logger": "gunicorn.access"}
```

Thanks
Jpw

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to change outer single quotes to double quotes and inner double quotes to single quotes as mentioned below.

```
--access-logformat  "{'remote_ip':'%(h)s','request_id':'%({X-Request-Id}i)s','response_code':'%(s)s','request_method':'%(m)s','request_path':'%(U)s','request_querystring':'%(q)s','request_timetaken':'%(D)s','response_length':'%(B)s'}"
```

**Following is sample log**

```
{'remote_ip':'127.0.0.1','request_id':'-','response_code':'404','request_method':'GET','request_path':'/test','request_querystring':'','request_timetaken':'6642','response_length':'233'}
{'remote_ip':'127.0.0.1','request_id':'-','response_code':'200','request_method':'GET','request_path':'/','request_querystring':'','request_timetaken':'881','response_length':'20'}
```

Comment: This answer was probably not accepted because single-quotes are not valid JSON. However, I wanted to point out that I easily able to swap out the single-quotes with double quotes by using replace: `somestring.replace("'", '"')`

Answer (score 5):

I was searching for something that would be useful in a logging config file.  Also, i am not a fan of manually constructing json formats by hand.
Solution:
All of of gunicorn's [logging arguments](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) are available in the record's args. So let's grab the fields from there and let pythonjsonlogger do the rest of the work for us.

Formatter Class

```py
from pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger import JsonFormatter, merge_record_extra


class GunicornLogFormatter(JsonFormatter): 
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        """
        This method allows us to inject gunicorn's args as fields for the formatter
        """
        super(GunicornLogFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        for field in self._required_fields:
            if field in self.rename_fields:
                log_record[self.rename_fields[field]] = record.args.get(field)
            else:
                log_record[field] = record.args.get(field)
```

Sample Logging Config File

```json
{
 "version": 1,
 "disable_existing_loggers": false,
 "formatters": {
  "gunicorn_json": {
   "()": "GunicornLogFormatter",
   "format": "%(h)s %(r)s %({x-request-id}i)s",
   "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z",
   "rename_fields": {
    "{x-request-id}i": "request_id",
    "r": "request"
   }
  }
 },
 "handlers": {
  "json-gunicorn-console": {
   "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
   "level": "INFO",
   "formatter": "gunicorn_json",
   "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
  }
 },
 "loggers": {
  "gunicorn.access": {
   "level": "INFO",
   "handlers": [
    "json-gunicorn-console"
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Sample Logs

```
{"h": "127.0.0.1", "request": "GET /login?next=/ HTTP/1.1", "request_id": null}
{"h": "127.0.0.1", "request": "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1", "request_id": null}
{"h": "127.0.0.1", "request": "GET /some/random/path HTTP/1.1", "request_id": null}
{"h": "127.0.0.1", "request": "GET /some/random/path HTTP/1.1", "request_id": "123123123123123123"}
```

Comment: Could you share an example how the log messages looks like?

Comment: How does one load that yaml-formatted logging config file?

Comment: You could use any yaml parser such as pyyaml and then call logging.config.dictConfig with the resulting dictionary. I did update the answer to use json instead since many W/ASGI implementations support json out of the box

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the double quotes (`\"`) directly in the value of `--access-logformat` to keep your logs as valid JSON.

So if you're running Gunicorn in a Docker container, your *Dockerfile* could end with something like:

```
CMD ["gunicorn",            \
    "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000",   \
    "--access-logfile", "-",\
    "--access-logformat", "{\"remote_ip\":\"%(h)s\",\"request_id\":\"%({X-Request-Id}i)s\",\"response_code\":\"%(s)s\",\"request_method\":\"%(m)s\",\"request_path\":\"%(U)s\",\"request_querystring\":\"%(q)s\",\"request_timetaken\":\"%(D)s\",\"response_length\":\"%(B)s\"}", \
    "app:create_app()"]
```

Find the rest of the Gunicorn logging options [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging).

Answer (score 1):

It's 2 years on and I'm assuming the fluentd python logger has changed, I get a slightly different issue now and every Google search points back to this discussion.

When using your example in a gunicorn config file

```
access_log_format = '{"remote_ip":"%(h)s","request_id":"%({X-Request-Id}i)s","response_code":"%(s)s","request_method":"%(m)s","request_path":"%(U)s","request_querystring":"%(q)s","request_timetaken":"%(D)s","response_length":"%(B)s"}'
```

I get the desired behaviour of reading this as json and merging it with the fluentd json data, however the gunicorn fields aren't populated

```
{"tags": [], "level": "INFO", "host": "ubuntu", "logger": "gunicorn.access", "remote_ip":"%(h)s","request_id":"%({X-Request-Id}i)s","response_code":"%(s)s","request_method":"%(m)s","request_path":"%(U)s","request_querystring":"%(q)s","request_timetaken":"%(D)s","response_length":"%(B)s"}
```

It looks like the reason for this is that Gunicorn passes `access_log_format` as the message to the logger, and all the parameters (`safe_atoms`) as additional params, e.g.

[/gunicorn/glogging.py](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/839d5dc66c086ec5aa0a97443fcd768eca1190f0/gunicorn/glogging.py#L349)

```
        safe_atoms = self.atoms_wrapper_class(
            self.atoms(resp, req, environ, request_time)
        )

        try:
            # safe_atoms = {"s": "200", "m": "GET", ...}
            self.access_log.info(self.cfg.access_log_format, safe_atoms)
```

however, if `FluentRecordFormatter` sees the string as valid json, it will read it using `json.loads` but ignores any arguments that are passed

[/fluent/handler.py](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-python/blob/7389fb6600f57b6eb21c854019df7d06a79fbb57/fluent/handler.py#L130)

```
    def _format_msg_json(self, record, msg):
        try:
            json_msg = json.loads(str(msg))  # <------- doesn't merge params
            if isinstance(json_msg, dict):
                return json_msg
            else:
                return self._format_msg_default(record, msg)
        except ValueError:
            return self._format_msg_default(record, msg)
```

Compare this to the [default Python formatter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46abfc1416ff8e450999611ef8f231ff871ab133/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L510) which calls `record.message = record.getMessage()` which in turn merges the arguments in

[/Lib/logging/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46abfc1416ff8e450999611ef8f231ff871ab133/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L360)

```
    def getMessage(self):
        """
        Return the message for this LogRecord.
        Return the message for this LogRecord after merging any user-supplied
        arguments with the message.
        """
        msg = str(self.msg)
        if self.args:
            msg = msg % self.args  # <------ args get merged in
        return msg
```

I've [logged an issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-python/issues/170) with the fluent-logger-python project.

### Workaround

Use a [logging filter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) to perform the merge before it's passed to `FluentRecordFormatter`.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('fluent.test')

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.msg = record.msg % record.args
        return True

fluent_handler = handler.FluentHandler('app.follow', host='localhost', port=24224)
formatter = handler.FluentRecordFormatter()
fluent_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
merge_filter = ContextFilter()
fluent_handler.addFilter(merge_filter)
logger.addHandler(fluent_handler)
```

### Edit: Logging Filter Doesn't Work

After using the workaround of a logging filter for a bit, I started receiving errors like

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ';' (0x3b) at index 166
```

It turns out that `FluentRecordFormatter` does call the base `getMessage` implementation, merging arguments into the message

```
    def format(self, record):
        # Compute attributes handled by parent class.
        super(FluentRecordFormatter, self).format(record)  # <------ record.messge = record.msg % record.args
        # Add ours
        record.hostname = self.hostname

        # Apply format
        data = self._formatter(record)

        self._structuring(data, record)
        return data
```

The problem is that `_format_msg_json(self, record, msg)` uses the `record.msg` attribute which is the **unmerged** data, whereas `record.message` is the merged data. This creates a problem that my logging filter was merging / formatting the data but then the log formatter was also trying to do that and occasionally seeing invalid syntax.

### Workaround 2: Don't Use Json

I've entirely given up on outputting json from gunicorn / python logging. Instead I'm using Fluentd's parser to parse the json, e.g.

```
<filter *.gunicorn.access>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  reserve_time true
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  hash_value_field access_log
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*) "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"$/
    time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
  </parse>
</filter>
```

You can read about what the options are doing here: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser